# Error when overloading operator< in sf::Vector

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, sfml

I want to use `std::map` with `sf::Vector2i` class, but for some reason I need to `overload < operator`. Since the map will represent a `3x3` grid, I came up with this to sort the vectors:

```
inline bool operator <(sf::Vector2i l, sf::Vector2i r)
{
    if (l.x * 3 + l.y < r.x * 3 + r.y) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But I still get error `C2678`

> no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const sf::Vector2i'

I did the same thing with my custom vector type and it worked, so what is causing this error?

**Edit:**

This overload is in a separate `.cpp` file.
I just wrapped this overload in a namespace `sf{}` and it worked. Why doesn't it work by just specifying `sf::Vector2i` in the parameters?

Comment: is it declared in a header?

Comment: In addition to immibis: The definition of operator must be "visible" where it is used. The usual way to do this: define it above to the function where you need it, or define it in a header file which is `#include`d in the file where you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with:

> I want to use `std::map` with `sf::Vector2i` class, but for some reason I need to overload `<` operator.

A `std::map` orders its contents by their keys, which requires knowing how to order the keys (presumably `sf::Vector2i`). By default, the definition of the order of the keys is given by `operator <`. That means that the map calls `operator<(const sf::Vector21&, const sf::Vector21&)` to determine if one key is less than another. Hence, this operator must be defined somewhere.

**If you are not interested in this order, you could try an `unordered_map` instead.**

> I just wrapped this overload in a namespace `sf{}` and it worked. Why doesn't it work by just specifying `sf::Vector2i` in the parameters?

This is probably a result of [the lookup rules for dependent names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name#Lookup_rules). Remember that call to `operator<`? It would be made somewhere deep inside templates, and the types of its arguments are dependent on template parameters. The relevant consequence for this is that the compiler will look for declarations visible from the template definition (deep in header files), plus whatever is found by argument-dependent lookup (ADL). Your overload is not visible from the template definition (nor should it), so it would need to be found by ADL. However, the arguments are both in the namespace `sf`, so ADL looks only in namespace `sf`. Hence the compiler can find an overload in the `sf` namespace, but not one elsewhere.

This is more commonly encountered when the arguments are in the `std` namespace, but should apply here as well. (Some of this is newish to me, so I might have messed up some details.) *The main takeaway is that trying to override operators acting on only classes in another namespace often fails.*

The good news is that you are not stuck. **A [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) takes more than two template parameters. The third one lets you specify how keys are to be compared.** Read up on the subject and see how far you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator does not, in fact, take a const Vector2i. The const is important!

Comment: Why is const a must in this case?

Comment: Sorry, it's not. I missed your edit that it works in the `sf` namespace. I agree with @JaMiT that this is probably a name lookup issue. Generally free functions, operators or otherwise, that are "part of" a class's interface should be declared in that same namespace. ADL will do the rest. By declaring operator< you are extending Vector2i's interface and should put it in that same namespace.

Comment: The `const` would be important if the parameter was passed by reference instead of value. (This answer was one of my first thoughts as well.) Speaking of which, passing by const reference instead of value would be a good  idea, @John.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, which is why I posted the answer in the first place. I read the description too quickly. Voted up you answer, though. I think it covers the essentials.

Comment: I hope I didn't give the wrong impression. I wasn't explaining to you, @ravnsgaard, so much as explaining to the random person reading these comments. ;)